# android json parsing - how to get the values according to the tag from list view

Tags: android, json, parsing

Following is the json data which i am getting from an api

```
{
     "list": {
        "items": [
            "About Us",
            "Services",
            "Working With",
            "Officehours",
            "Useful Links",
            "Terms & Conditions",
            "Go to Website"
        ]
    },
    "data": 
    {
        "about us": {  "description": " Aaaaaaaa"   },
        "services": {  "description": " Baaaaaaa."  },
        "working with": { "description": "Caaaaaa"  },
        "officehours": {   "title": "Office Hours:","timing": "09:00am - 06:00pm"},
        "useful links": {  "description": [ 
                 {
                    "name": "One",
                    "link": "http://www.google.com/"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Two",
                    "link": "http://www.yahoo.com"
                }]},
        "terms & conditions": { "description": "Daaaaaaaaa" },
        "go to website": { "link": "http: //www.amazon.com/"  },
    }
}
```

In the above json data the "list" values in the json array are to be show in a listview. I have added them in an array list and shown in a list view too.

Now when the user clicks on the list view the data corresponding to them are shown in the next activity. For example if the user clicks on the `About US text of listview` then i how to show the `description Aaaaaaa` in the next activity.

Like this for each item in list view i have to open different activity. 
If the inner tag is `description` i have to open `activity1`
If the inner tag is `title` i have to open `activity2`
If the inner tag is `link` i have to open `activity3`
If the inner tag is `description` is to be an JSON array type, have to open `activity4`

I am not supposed to hot code the tags such as `"about us", "services","working with","officehours","useful links","terms & conditions", "go to website"` within the code.

In my OnItemClickListener  i am doing the following

```
try
  {
     JSONObject locarray = new JSONObject(Appconstant.dataObj.get(0).toString());        
     String txt_data = locarray.getJSONObject(about.get(arg2).toLowerCase()).getString("description");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      Log.e("Exception @ json 1",""+e);
  }
```

in some cases i am getting an exception saying that there is no JSOn value of "description"

how to get this to be done, pls help me

Comment: Who creates that JSON data? Is it under your control?

Comment: no its from an api and we cant change it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way of doing it is by

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(content); // the content you have above
JSONObject data = jobj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject aboutUs = data.getJSONObject("about us");
String desc = aboutUs.getString("description:);
```

not sure if this might help :)  if there is a case were the description is blank use

```
aboutUs.optString("description");
```

Comment: but i am not supposed to use this "about us" directly in the code, because this may get changed in future....

Comment: You can use jobj.keys and you will get an Iterator of the String names for the object.  you can then build a recursive method to traverse through the JSON object.  not sure if the gives you a hint to your solution...